# To access "Agreement, tax and banking" in App store connect

Tags: ios, store

[Homepage of the App Store connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsS1A.png)

How do I access "Agreement, tax and banking" in the current version of App store connect?
Before there was an icon, but I'm not finding it in the current version.

Trank you,

Comment: What access level does your user have?

Comment: I am an iOS developer. Once approved, the status of my application has been changed to "Contract pending". So I need access to agreement, tax and banking.

Comment: Do you have a personal or an organisational membership?  If you have an organisational membership does your account have the admin or finance roles assigned?

Comment: Personal. My account and data are already registered. I believe I have to agree to the contract. This is accomplished through the app store connect.